# Does Thrumming Stone ripple after ripple

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Thrumming Stone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thrumming%20Stone) says:

> Spells you cast have ripple 4. (Whenever you **cast a spell**, you may reveal the top four cards of your library. You may **cast any revealed cards** with the same name as the spell without paying their mana costs. Put the rest on the bottom of your library.)

Does this mean then when I cast a spell (e.g. [Relentless Rats](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Relentless%20Rats)):
I look at the top 4 cards which contains a Relentless rat,
I cast this card and then ripple again?

And if I find two rats in one ripple does this mean I can look at my next 8 cards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does work like that.  That's part of the point of Ripple... if your deck is built correctly, you can just keep on Rippling all the way through it.

This ruling on Thrumming Stone in Gatherer may be instructive:

> If you cast a spell that already has ripple (such as Surging Flame,
>   which has ripple 4) while Thrumming Stone is on the battlefield, both
>   ripple abilities will trigger separately. Assuming you choose to do
>   all "you may" actions, when the first instance of ripple resolves, you
>   reveal the top four cards of your library, cast all Surging Flames,
>   and put the rest of the cards on the bottom of your library. Any new
>   Surging Flames are on the stack on top of the other instance of
>   ripple, so they'll resolve next. Each of them also has two instances
>   of ripple, which trigger separately, and the process continues until
>   the ripple abilities don't reveal any Surging Flames.

As you can see, each new copy of Surging Flames has not one but *two* instances of Ripple (one granted by Thrumming Stone) which resolve.  Ripple keeps on going until there's nothing with Ripple left to cast.

Comment: So if you play an EDH deck with 30 Relentless rats, you can get them all out with just one rat? (if you are lucky)

Comment: @SirDuckduck If you play an EDH deck with 30 Relentless Rats, you aren't playing an EDH deck. "With the exception of basic lands, no two cards in the deck may have the same English name."

Comment: @SocioMatt But the ruling of Relentless rats says: A deck can have any number of cards named Relentless Rats.

Comment: @SirDuckduck 100.2a of the Comp Rules says in constructed play that a deck can contain "no more than four of any card." But the rules for EDH are worded differently: 903.5b says that each card "**must** have a different English name." I think the word "must" would indicate that multiple copies of any card would be illegal. Additionally, I personally feel that Relentless Rats violates the spirit of EDH; I'd be incredibly annoyed if someone did this in an EDH game, and I feel like most other players would, too.

Comment: @SocioMatt Its just a deck for fun anyway, so i don't really care about the ruling. I just wondered if i could get all my rats in play.

Comment: You CAN have any number of copies of Relentless Rats in an EDH/Commander deck. It's the golden rule of Magic: "101. The Magic Golden Rules
101.1. Whenever a card's text directly contradicts these rules, the card takes precedence. The card overrides only the rule that applies to that specific situation. The only exception is that a player can concede the game at any time (see rule 104.3a)."

Comment: @GendoIkari Gah! Just started looking around and it seems the internet agrees with you (probably because you're right). But I stand by my statement of it violating the spirit of EDH.

Comment: @SocioMatt Relentless Rats allow you to play a number of Johnny cards that otherwise wouldn't work in EDH, like Bloodbond March, Thrumming Stone, and Doubling Chant. Even the most combo-tastic Relentless Rats decks don't go off super-fast and are easy to interact with using commonly-used EDH cards (like sweepers). That's entirely within the "spirit" of the format.

Comment: I posted a response out in chat so that the discussion doesn't continue here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The first rat will ripple and then each subsequent casting of the spell 'relentless rats' will ripple, because the triggered ability will happen each time you cast a spell.

Note that this is a may trigger. Which means once it is on the stack, you may choose to do it or you may choose not to do it when it comes time to resolve the ripple effect.